# Relationship between matrix and dimension

Tags: matrices

I think a matrix can be seen as a collection of vectors, but isn't it connected to a dimension?
But I also don't organize my thoughts well...
I am curious about the relationship between matrix and dimension.

Comment: When you represent a linear application $\varphi : E \rightarrow F$ by a matrix $M \in \mathcal{M}_{pq}(\mathbb{K})$, then $p$ is the dimension of $F$ and $q$ is the dimension of $E$. That is, you read the dimensions of the spaces on the size on the matrix.

Comment: The column rank of a matrix $M$ is defined as the dimension of the space spanned by the columns of $M$ and is denoted $rank(M)$